# Undeclared identifier error in pinescript

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to convert the following pinescript code converted to version4. I get Undeclared identifier error. can someone please help me?

```
//Declare General Trend
TL1(src, len) =>
    weight = 3.5 / (len + 1)
    sum = nz(sum[1]) - nz(src[len]) + src
    ma = na(src[len]) ? na : sum/len
    out = na(out[1]) ? ma : (src - out[1]) * weight + out[1]
    out
TL(src, len) =>
    weight = 2 / (len + 1)
    sum = nz(sum[1]) - nz(src[len]) + src
    ma = na(src[len]) ? na : sum/len
    out = na(out[1]) ? ma : (src - out[1]) * weight + out[1]
    out    
   
TL3 = TL(low,16) - TL1(low,16)
TL4 = percentrank(TL3, 8)
TL5 = (TL3 < 0 and TL4 > 75) ? 1 : 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't confirm without compilable code, but this should work. Starting in v3, variables must be declared prior to using them with the history-referencing `[ ]` operator. Also, using `var` only declares the vars on the first bar, so propagates their value across bars and often makes it unnecessary to use `[1]` to refer to their previous value:

```
//Declare General Trend
TL1(src, len) =>
    var float sum = 0.
    var float out = na
    weight = 3.5 / (len + 1)
    sum := sum - nz(src[len]) + src
    ma = na(src[len]) ? na : sum/len
    out := na(out) ? ma : (src - out) * weight + out
    out
TL(src, len) =>
    var float sum = 0.
    var float out = na
    weight = 2 / (len + 1)
    sum := sum - nz(src[len]) + src
    ma = na(src[len]) ? na : sum/len
    out := na(out) ? ma : (src - out) * weight + out
    out    
   
TL3 = TL(low,16) - TL1(low,16)
TL4 = percentrank(TL3, 8)
TL5 = (TL3 < 0 and TL4 > 75) ? 1 : 0
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is it ok for you to look into my other query at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63953374/getting-an-cannot-call-abs-with-arguments-error-while-trying-to-convert-pinesc Thank you in advance