# Getting an Cannot call 'abs' with arguments error while trying to convert pinescript code to version 4

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to convert a pinescript code into version 4. The code is below

```
Early = abs((close[3] > open[3] and close[2] > open[2] and close[1] > open[1] and close < open) or (close[3] > open[3] and close[2] > open[2] and close[1] < open[1] and close > open) or (close[3] > open[3] and close[2] < open[2] and close[1] > open[1] and close > open) or (close[3] < open[3] and close[2] > open[2] and close[1] > open[1] and close > open) or (close[3] > open[3] and close[2] > open[2] and close[1] > open[1] and close > open))*(low*.9999525)
  
EarlyD = abs((close[3] < open[3] and close[2] < open[2] and close[1] < open[1] and close > open) or (close[3] < open[3] and close[2] < open[2] and close[1] > open[1] and close < open) or (close[3] < open[3] and close[2] > open[2] and close[1] < open[1] and close < open) or (close[3] > open[3] and close[2] < open[2] and close[1] < open[1] and close < open) or (close[3] < open[3] and close[2] < open[2] and close[1] < open[1] and close < open))*(high*1.00009525)
 
EarlyTd = abs(close > TL(low, 16) and close < l)*(low*.9999525)
EarlyTu = abs(close < TH(high, 16) and close > h)*(high*1.00009525)
```

I get the following error:

```
line 113: Cannot call 'abs' with arguments (series[bool]); available overloads: abs(integer) => integer; abs(input integer) => input integer; abs(const integer) => const integer; abs(float) => float; abs(input float) => input float; abs(const float) => const float; abs(series[float]) => series[float];
line 114: Cannot call 'abs' with arguments (series[bool]); available overloads: abs(integer) => integer; abs(input integer) => input integer; abs(const integer) => const integer; abs(float) => float; abs(input float) => input float; abs(const float) => const float; abs(series[float]) => series[float];

line 113: Cannot call 'operator *' with arguments (series[bool], series[float]); available overloads: *(const integer, const integer) => const integer; *(const float, const float) => const float; *(input integer, input integer) => input integer; *(input float, input float) => input float; *(integer, integer) => integer; *(float, float) => float; *(series[integer], series[integer]) => series[integer]; *(series[float], series[float]) => series[float];
line 115: Cannot call 'operator *' with arguments (series[bool], series[float]); available overloads: *(const integer, const integer) => const integer; *(const float, const float) => const float; *(input integer, input integer) => input integer; *(input float, input float) => input float; *(integer, integer) => integer; *(float, float) => float; *(series[integer], series[integer]) => series[integer]; *(series[float], series[float]) => series[float];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for something more like this. You can't operate on boolean expressions with numerical values, so here we do it in two steps: first we define our conditions (the boolean values), then we build prices using them.

```
// #1: Build boolean conditions.
EarlyU = (close[3] > open[3] and close[2] > open[2] and close[1] > open[1] and close < open) 
  or (close[3] > open[3] and close[2] > open[2] and close[1] < open[1] and close > open) 
  or (close[3] > open[3] and close[2] < open[2] and close[1] > open[1] and close > open) 
  or (close[3] < open[3] and close[2] > open[2] and close[1] > open[1] and close > open) 
  or (close[3] > open[3] and close[2] > open[2] and close[1] > open[1] and close > open)
  
EarlyD = (close[3] < open[3] and close[2] < open[2] and close[1] < open[1] and close > open) 
  or (close[3] < open[3] and close[2] < open[2] and close[1] > open[1] and close < open) 
  or (close[3] < open[3] and close[2] > open[2] and close[1] < open[1] and close < open) 
  or (close[3] > open[3] and close[2] < open[2] and close[1] < open[1] and close < open) 
  or (close[3] < open[3] and close[2] < open[2] and close[1] < open[1] and close < open)
 
EarlyTd = close > TL(low, 16) and close < l
EarlyTu = close < TH(high, 16) and close > h


// #2: Build prices.
EarlyUVal  = EarlyU  ? low  * 0.9999525  : na
EarlyDVal  = EarlyD  ? low  * 0.9999525  : na
EarlyTdVal = EarlyTd ? high * 1.00009525 : na
EarlyTuVal = EarlyTu ? high * 1.00009525 : na
```

Comment: Thanks you. Is it ok to have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64117980/how-to-find-the-closest-value-in-pinescript-array where I am trying to get the closest value to current price